# cardinality of the set of order isomorphism functions from (R,<) to itself

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Let $A$ be the set of order isomorphism functions (bijective and order preserving) from $(R,<)$ to itself. What is the cardinality of $A$? It's suppose to be $\mathfrak{c}$, but I'm having a hard time proving it.

Comment: Are you having trouble showing that $\vert A\vert\le\mathfrak{c}$ or that $\vert A\vert\ge\mathfrak{c}$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I'm having trouble showing that $|A| \leq c$.

Comment: Right, that is indeed the trickier definition. At a glance, the obvious upper bound is the number of maps $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, which is $2^\mathfrak{c}$ rather than $\mathfrak{c}$. But we can do better. Suppose I want to completely describe an **bijective order-preserving** map $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Can you think of a *countable* set of inputs which suffice to describe $f$ completely (that is, once I know what $f$ does to each real in this set, I know $f$'s entire behavior)?

Comment: Hint: prove the slightly stronger statement that there are only $\mathfrak{c}$ many increasing functions (either strictly or non-strictly)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I was thinking in that direction by looking at the behavior on Q, as it is dense inR, but it doesn't seem to be one-to-one (2 functions that are equal on Q aren't necessarily equal on R). Is there an other countable set that does work?

Comment: @AdiHendel Indeed, two functions that are equal on $\Bbb Q$ aren't necessarily equal on $\Bbb R$. But you know more about these things than just the fact that they are functions. You know they are strictly increasing, and you know the image of $\Bbb Q$ is always dense (or maybe you should prove that). Now take two of _those_ functions that are equal on $\Bbb Q$ and see what you can do.

Comment: @Arthur thanks! the density of the image of Q was the missing piece of the puzzle, I've managed to solve it now.